# PHP SQL injection prevention without parameter binding

Tags: php, sql-injection, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I am working for a video streaming website for my college library. I am using PHP and MySql. I have not used any parameterized queries in this project.

Recently I came to know about SQL injections. Now that my code is almost done and I have to submit the project in the next two days, how can I now ensure that my code is not SQL injection prone?

Converting the whole thing in to a parameterized interface is what I can't do now. What should I do now to avoid SQL Injections on my website?

Comment: @kjy112 i cant modify the code now !

Comment: @Arihant, why can't you?  Do you not have access to it anymore?

Comment: Really, this is one of the most asked and best answered question only askable. Sometimes I feel like for some people the search field isn't displayed...

Comment: @Brad: I have very less time left. And some other basic modules are yet to be completed.

Comment: @nikic Can you help me in finding any of those having the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea to prevent SQL injections *(if not using Prepared Statements)* is to **escape your data**.

When you inject some expected integer value into an SQL query, make sure it's an integer, using [**`intval()`**](https://www.php.net/intval).

When you have a decimal/numeric field in your table, use [**`floatval()`**](https://www.php.net/floatval).

And when you have a string *(char, varchar, text)* field in your table, use the function provided by your API to escape strings :

- [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
- [**`mysqli_real_escape_string()`**](http://fr.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)
- [**`PDO::quote()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend that you go back and do it right with parameterized queries.  It is the only solid path towards security.  It likely won't take too long to do this once you get started.

You should also know that websites are never "finished".  When you launch a site, your work has just begun.  Fixing security troubles as you learn about them is part of it, and this is no different.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure any user provided inputs that get used in SQL queries are escaped using the PHP function `mysql_real_escape_string` and if you are letting people submit text to run `htmlentities` on the provided text so XXS isn't possible.  If possible, white-list user provided input and discard anything else

This is just touching the surface of what you can do but look into query escaping and preventing cross site scripting.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  You should at least reference `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Actually, what I mention are preventive measures.  This is what he asks for and he even states he can't parameterize the queries.

Comment: Thanks for changing your post.  I have undone my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO (or alternatively mysqli or some abstraction layer) and prepared statements.

Quick example:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($unsafe_id));
$name = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

In this example, `$unsafe_id` will be safe to use. To quote the manual page:

> Calling PDO::prepare() and
>   PDOStatement::execute() for statements
>   that will be issued multiple times
>   with different parameter values
>   optimizes the performance of your
>   application by allowing the driver to
>   negotiate client and/or server side
>   caching of the query plan and meta
>   information, and helps to prevent SQL
>   injection attacks by eliminating the
>   need to manually quote the parameters.
>
> PDO will emulate prepared
>   statements/bound parameters for
>   drivers that do not natively support
>   them, and can also rewrite named or
>   question mark style parameter markers
>   to something more appropriate, if the
>   driver supports one style but not the
>   other.